# Can I format TIME data type on JavaDB?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, javadb

I have a TIME data type column in my database. According to [this](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefsqlj21908.html), it supports **hh[:mm] {AM | PM}** format. But when I tried insert this sql :

```
INSERT INTO POSISI (ID, TUJUAN, PELABUHAN_TERAKHIR, LATLNG, AREA, KECEPATAN, HALUAN, STATUS, KETERANGAN, WAKTU, JAM) VALUES ((SELECT ID FROM KAPAL WHERE UPPER(KAPAL.NAMA)=UPPER('Aura Kasih')), 'Surabaya', 'Karimun', '2.02, 100.2', 'Kiclik', '19 knot', '11°', 'Anchor', 'Aman', '2014-03-16', '01:50 AM')
```

I got this on my database :

```
2 | Surabaya | Karimun | 2.02, 100.2 | Kiclik | 19 knot | 11° | Anchor | Aman | 2014-03-16 | 01:50:00
```

As you can see, I am using **01:50 AM** but it stored as **01:50:00**.

So, can I tell JavaDB to store TIME as **hh:mm a** format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time will always be stored as hh:mm:ss in the db. The format that you mentioned is for the input. You will need to format the time again when you want to retrieve / display from the db.